# How can i separate key/value in different array object in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have this in my code:

```
let obj = {EdadBeneficiario1: '32', EdadBeneficiario2: '5'}
var years = [];
let i;
for (i= obj;i<=obj;i++)
{
years.push({ edad_beneficiario : i })
}
```

the output is

```
[
edad_beneficiario:{EdadBeneficiario1:"32", EdadBeneficiario2:"5"}
]
```

but what i want is this

```
[
 {edad_beneficiario:"32"},
 {edad_beneficiario:"5"}
]
```

what can i do?

EDIT

By the way, if i do this

```
years.push({ edad_beneficiario :obj.EdadBeneficiario1})
years.push({ edad_beneficiario :obj.EdadBeneficiario2})
```

the output what i want resolve but i want it to do it with a for loop. Please, Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? Use `Object.values()` and `Array.map()` to get the desired output.

```js
let obj = {
  EdadBeneficiario1: '32',
  EdadBeneficiario2: '5'
}

const output = Object.values(obj).map(value => ({
  edad_beneficiario: value
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the loop, you are setting `i = obj`, then `i = {EdadBeneficiario1: '32', EdadBeneficiario2: '5'}`. `i` must be a integer value to work with the for loop in this case. You can use `Object.values` method to transform `obj` values into an array and get it's data to use it in the `for` loop.

```
let obj = {EdadBeneficiario1: '32', EdadBeneficiario2: '5'}
var years = [];
let objValuesArray = Object.values(obj);
for (let i = 0; i < objValuesArray.length; i++) {
  years.push({ edad_beneficiario : objValuesArray[i] })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {EdadBeneficiario1: '32', EdadBeneficiario2: '5'}
var years = [];

Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    years.push( {edad_beneficiario: value} )
}
)

console.log(years)
/*
  Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​  0: Object { edad_beneficiario: "32" }
​  1: Object { edad_beneficiario: "5" }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              const myFunc = (obj) => {
                   const years = Object.keys(obj).map((c, i) => {
                   const values = Object.values(obj).map((b) => b);

                    return { edad_beneficiario: values[i] };
                        });
                     console.log(years);
                 };
```

you can actually make it a lot shorter but i just wanted you to know that you can access object keys as well .